# How to add the total of a specific set of rows of a column, and then add this to another dataset?

Tags: r

So I have two data sets the first being the OWID Covid-19 Dataset available [here](https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/tree/master/public/data), it contains a column including location names and the total number of new covid cases for each day reported. It looks something like this:[image] I would like to add the total number of new cases column but only for a specific location, the only methods we have been taught on my course are for totalling the whole column, but I would only like to add the rows corresponding to specific location for example Afghanistan, to then get a total number of covid cases for that country (by adding the total number of new cases).

After this is complete I would like to then add this result to another dataset, as a new column for the locations total Covid-19 cases, the dataset I am adding this to looks like this (so for each location there should be a new column with their total number of covid cases corresponding to each location):[image]

TLDR:

1. How do I add rows of a column relating to a specific variable in another column, or just by entering row/column number?
2. How would I then add this results to another data set by the location name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result using `dplyr` library in R.
First, you'll need to group the data using the `location` variable and then summarise the column of `new_cases`.

The code will look like this:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  summarise(totalCases = sum(new_cases))
df
```

The output will look like this:

```
# A tibble: 238 x 2
   location            totalCases
   <chr>                    <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan             158602
 2 Africa                10230722
 3 Albania                     NA
 4 Algeria                 224383
 5 Andorra                     NA
 6 Angola                   92581
 7 Anguilla                    NA
 8 Antigua and Barbuda         NA
 9 Argentina                   NA
10 Armenia                     NA
# ... with 228 more rows
```

**Note**: This will give you `totalCases` for every location.

To get it for a specific location, you can use `filter`.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  filter(location == "Afghanistan") %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  summarise(totalCases = sum(new_cases))
df2
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  location    totalCases
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 Afghanistan     158602
```

Since it is stored in a new df called `df2`, you can merge the data with another df of your choice.
You can find the documentation [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html).

Comment: Thank you so much this works absolutely fine! I checked out the documentation and this will work thank you!

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick on the left and upvoting.

Comment: Hi I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote sorry or else I would.

Comment: You can accept the answer though.